# Google Analytics API numbers don't add up

Tags: mysql, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics API to get unique-pageviews, and pageviews.

All the data I pull is then stored in a DB table. The data I pull is from 24 hours ago and 48 hours ago. If the data pulled from 48 hours ago conflicts with the data pulled 24 hours ago MySQL replaces it. To make sure the data is good.

Now when I compare the data using Google API Explorer and compare the pageviews for each day the data is equal so everything is good for every individual day.

But here is where it gets really weird. If I say for example start-date = 2015-02-15 and end-date = 2015-02-21.

In MySQL I get the sum of all the pageviews and I even double check with my handy calculator. The numbers are good. But when I use the same date range in Google API Explorer I get a different number. Again remember for each day I have the same numbers it's only with the date range I get something different. So is it Google that does not understand math or is it that when you have a wide date range Google adds numbers from some other planet... What is going on?

Here is an example:

From the DB:

### Post ID | unique pageviews | Page views | Date

| 2429387 | 155 | 183 | 2015-02-15

| 2429387 | 140 | 158 | 2015-02-16

| 2429387 | 134 | 147 | 2015-02-17

| 2429387 | 129 | 144 | 2015-02-18

| 2429387 | 113 | 120 | 2015-02-19

| 2429387 | 116 | 139 | 2015-02-20

| 2429387 | 132 | 156 | 2015-02-21

Again all these numbers are the same the Google API gives me with Google API Explorer. So each day is good.

DB again but the sum:

### Post ID | sum unique pageviews | sum Page views | Date

2429387 | 919 | 1,047 | 2015-02-15 | 2015-02-21

Google API Explorer:

[
   "2429387", -> post ID

"975", -> Unique Pageviews

"1097" -> Pageviews
  ],

Also why am I getting another set of data when I look in Google Analytics interface. Shouldn't it give me the same numbers that we see in the Google API Explorer?

[image]

Comment: I haven't used Google api explorer but, is it possible that the api includes or excludes the last day?

Comment: This is the thing. I have no idea. Also when I look at their Google Analytics interface... I also get a different set of numbers even in the day. It's very confusing. And the documentation is just not clear at all.

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? Is sampling an issue for you?

Comment: I have been doing some research. And it seems to be a sampling issue.

Comment: I will be paying my writers based on the number of unique pageviews.